# Passing by reference to a thread C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, ref

I have a method that I intend to run on its own thread, but can't figure out how to pass the reference when setting up the thread.

```c#
 private void ManageConnections(ref List<string> instanceAddresses) 
        {
            int connected = Instances.Count();

            if(instanceAddresses.Count() > connected)
            {
                int instancesToAdd = instanceAddresses.Count() - connected;

                while(instancesToAdd != 0)
                {
                    Channel channel = new Channel(instanceAddresses[instanceAddresses.Count - instancesToAdd], ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
                    var client = new ConfigurationDirectoryService.ConfigurationDirectoryServiceClient(channel);
                    Instances.Add(client);
                    instancesToAdd--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Desired behaviour is that when the original list (instanceAddresses) is changed, this method can get to work and can set up a new client and add it to another list.

This is the method that would call the thread start:

```c#
 public CDS_Service(ref List<string> instanceAddresses)
        {
            Thread manageAvaliable = new Thread(CheckAvaliability);
            manageAvaliable.Start();

            if(instanceAddresses.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach(string instanceAddr in instanceAddresses)
                {
                    Channel channel = new Channel(instanceAddr, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
                    var client = new ConfigurationDirectoryService.ConfigurationDirectoryServiceClient(channel);
                    Instances.Add(client);
                }

                foreach(CM commandManager in Instances[0].SyncDirectory(new Empty { }).CommandManagers)
                {
                    List<string> commands = new List<string>();

                    foreach(string command in commandManager.Commands)
                    {
                        commands.Add(command);
                    }

                    Directory.Add(new CommandManager(commandManager.Address, commands, commandManager.IsActive));
                }
            }

//Thread would be setup here
        }
```

And where this is constructed:

```c#
Server server = new Server
            {
                Services = { ConfigurationDirectoryService.BindService(new CDS_Service(ref clientDiscovery.OtherInstances)) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort(addr, PORT, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
            };
```

I'm also not sure if this is also bad practice passing a ref around through different classes like this.

Is this possible/safe to do?

Comment: This is not where you should use pass-by-reference. You should use an observable collection.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, didn't know this was a thing. However, I am passing this list as a constructor to this class as it comes from somewhere else. Again, not sure if this is bad practice or not.

Comment: Can you show the caller side of the method as well?

Comment: So do you intend to call `ManageCollections` on the line `//Thread would be setup here`? You still haven't shown where `instanceAddresses` came from. Basically, wherever it comes from, change that to an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry it wasn't clear, yeah ManageCollections would be called there. instanceAddreses is a reference that is passed in (See the bottom snippet) the constructor. It comes from another class (clientDiscovery)

Comment: Oh I see it now. Can you change `clientDiscovery.OtherInstances` to a `ObservableCollection<string>`?

Comment: @Sweeper I have done so, how do I access this within the thread seeming its in another class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ref` here, you should use an observable collection, like `ObservableCollection<T>`. `List<string>` is already pass-by-reference :)

First, change the type of `clientDiscovery.OtherInstances` to `ObservableCollection<string>`, then change the parameter type of the constructor to `ObservableCollection<string>` as well. Remove all the `ref`s, you don't need those.

Now, rewrite `ManageConnections` to this signature (You'll need `using System.Collections.Specialized`):

```
private void ManageConnections(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {

}
```

Here, you will check `e.NewItems` to see which items have been added to the `instanceAddresses` list, and add each of them to another list:

```
foreach (var item in e.NewItems) {
    Channel channel = new Channel(item, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
    var client = new ConfigurationDirectoryService.ConfigurationDirectoryServiceClient(channel);
    Instances.Add(client);
}
```

You might want to do something if the there are removed items as well. If you want to handle that, use `e.OldItems`. Those are the removed items.

Now, instead of calling `ManageConnections`, you do:

```
instancesToAdd.CollectionChanged += ManageConnections;
```

Note that this won't handle the initial items in the list (only subsequent changes will be added), so you might want to handle the initial items straight after the line above.

Comment: This looks great, thanks for your help! I'm handling the initial items else where so this looks exactly like what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `ref` keyword. `List<T>` is a class which is a reference type, so it's already passed by reference.

Well, to be precise you're passing the reference around, and THAT is passed by value. You would only need the `ref` keyword if you assigned the reference to a new / different list and wanted that passed back to the caller.

If you do not intend to alter the list, then you're probably better passing `IEnumerable<T>` instead, since that is read only .`List<T>` already implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you don't even need to cast.

If you're accessing the list from different threads, then be aware it could change AT ANY TIME (like half way through iterating it). In this case you may want a `ConcurrentList<T>` which is at least thread safe for add/removes. Alternatively if you're only reading, you may be better to create a readonly "snapshot" of the list at a certain point by calling `ToArray()` on it or something and passing that around instead.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the input. Yeah the List is only being changed within the class it is created, just being read around other places. If this list was to change, would it then update in the new thread also if I understand correctly?

Comment: Correct. It's the same list.